# How create summary table for every column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrames with around 100 columns each. I have to create a summary table for all of those columns. In the summary Dataframe I want to have a name (one from every of these data frames and this I'm doing okay) and put mean and std of every column.

So my final table should have the shape: n x m
where n is the number of files
and m is the number of columns x 2 (mean and std)

Something like this

```
name    mean_col1   std_col1    mean_col2   std_col2 
ABC        22.815293    0.103567    90.277533   0.333333
DCE        22.193991    0.12389     87.17391    0.123457
```

I tried following but I'm not getting what I wanted:

```
list_with_names = []
list_for_mean_and_std = []

for file in glob.glob("/data/path/*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    output = {'name':df['name'][0]}
    
    list_with_names.append(output)
    
    numerical_cols = df.select_dtypes('float64')
    
    for column in numerical_cols:
        mean_col = numerical_cols[column].mean()
        std_col = numerical_cols[column].std()
        
        output_2 = {'mean': mean_col,
                    'std': std_col}
        
        list_for_mean_and_std.append(output_2)
        
    
summary = pd.DataFrame(list_with_names, list_for_mean_and_std)
```

And I'm getting an error `Shape of passed values is (183, 1), indices imply (7874, 1)` because I'm assigning in the wrong way these values with means and std but I have no idea how.

I will be glad for any advice on how to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of coruse, Pandas have a [method for that - `describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

```py
df.describe()
```

Which gives more statistics than you requested. If you are interested only in mean and std, you can do:

```py
df.describe()[['mean', 'std']]
```

Comment: I would like to create my own function since I will need also on this table do other calculations per column, but once I will know how to get such a summary DataFrame should be easy. :)

Comment: You are getting an error because `list_with_names` and `list_for_mean_and_std` have different lengths. It's not easy to follow your code because you start by loading the dataframe, saving it into a dict, appending the dict into a list (`list_with_names`), than loading it back to a dataframe. Why not loading all the files into a single dataframe, you can create a new column indicating the filename if it's important to keep them separated, and do your calculation on the big dataframe? Makes more sense to me.

Comment: Create big Dataframe and then group-by this name? (I need to have summary per every name - it's provide ID) I will try and if I will not succeed I will update question, thanks

Comment: Exactly. Let me know (by posting another comment here so I get a notification, I guess?) once you updated or created a new question, will be glad to help.

Comment: Everything works - I used groupby(by='name').agg('mean'). Thanks a lot :)